# Jquery rails 3, move item from one div class to another div when it is checked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

i have two div id=left and div id=right. now, there are multiple checkboxes with item listed in left div. when i select one check box then that item should remove from left div and added to right div and do it same for move selected item from div id=right to div id=left. and when i click one check box its status also updated in database. so tell me how to perform this task with jquery-ajax in rails 3.

Script :

```
        <script>
          $(function () {

            $(".checkbox").click(function() {

              $('.allchkb').each(function(){

                var item = $(this).attr('id');
                  if($(this).is(':checked')){
                  $("#right > span."+item).appendTo("#left");
                  $(this).siblings("#left").css("text-decoration","line-through");
                  $(this).siblings("#left").css("color","#aaa");
                  $(this).parent('li').css("background-color","#ccc");

                  } 
                  else 
                  {
                    $("#left > span."+item).appendTo("#right");
                  }
              });
            });
         });
      </script>
```

rails code:

```
     <div class="box-body box-body-nopadding" id="left">
      <% @activity.each do |p| %>
        <% p.task.each do |t| %>
          <ul class="tasklist">
            <li class="bookmarked">
              <label class="checkbox">
                <%= check_box_tag 'activity_status', task.id, :class => 'checkbox'%>
              <%= link_to task.title, mytask_path(@task), :title => "is responsible.                                 , Total my task : " %>
               <span class="task-actions">
                 <%= link_to "Edit", task(@activity) %> |
                 <%= link_to "delete", @task, :method => :delete %>

              </span>
              <span class="task-actions">
                <%= task.due_date %> 
              </span>
            </li><li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
      <div class="box-body box-body-nopadding" id="right">
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Generally, some code is given to help solve the problem at hand, we will not write everything for you :).

Comment: have added jquery and checkbox list code. and i dnt knw much about ajax. so when i select item it should b updated in data-base

Comment: Yeah, done with this question....